# Getting all different values but not duplicates from multiple records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT o.order_id, ol.product_manufacturer 
FROM orders o 
INNER JOIN order_lines ol 
ON o.order_id = ol.order_id 
WHERE o.deadline_time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

I also have these tables:

```
orders:
order_id, somefield, somefield, somefield...

order_lines:
id, order_id, product_manufacturer, somefield, somefield...
```

I want to get all orders where deadline hasn't passed and group them by product_manufacturer, but if an order has three order lines, that all have the product_manufacturer id, then it should only return the id ones. If it has the two order lines with different product_manufacturer id, then it should return the id twice and so on.

I'm using PHP and I would like to end up with an array like this:

```
$group[manufacturer_id] = array(order_id, order_id, order_id);
```

**EDIT: Actually I want it to return manufacturer_id = 999, if there are multiple manufacturer ids in an order. Sorry for the mistake.**

**EDIT2: I'm making a listing of all orders, but I have to list them by their manufacturer. Like so:**

```
SONY
Order 1
Order 2
Order 16
Order 99

PROSONIC
Order 3
Order 88
Order 98
```

Later it should be possible to search, so I will have to make something like WHERE ol.product_name LIKE '%$query', but I will add that later on, when it works.

Comment: @Strawberry - SELECT DISTINCT will not get me the order_id, if it differs in the order_lines

Comment: @UlrikMcArdle - you are asking for `all orders` which sounds like you want plain data. But then you as for `group them by product_manufacturer`, and return again for `return the id ones`. Can you try please to rephrase or draw a table how would you like to see the output?

Comment: much better, is `Order` `orders.order_id` or `order_lines.id`

Comment: @LuisLL - Order is the o.order_id or ol.order_id same

Comment: @LuisLL - I'm trying to do something like this: SELECT o.order_id, 
IF(
    (
        SELECT COUNT(tmp_o.order_id) 
        FROM orders tmp_o 
        INNER JOIN order_lines tmp_ol
        ON tmp_o.order_id = tmp_ol.order_id 
        WHERE o.deadline_time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
    ) = 1, 
    ol.product_manufacturer, 999
) AS product_manufacturer
FROM orders o 
INNER JOIN order_lines ol 
ON o.order_id = ol.order_id 
WHERE o.order_id = o.order_id 
ORDER BY o.deadline_time

This doesn't work.

Comment: so why not adding `ORDER BY ol.product_manufacturer, o.order_id`?

Comment: Yes, I probably should do that, but I does not give me the 999, if there are more than 2 manufacturer on an order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT o.order_id,group_concat(distinct(ol.product_manufacturer )) as manufacturer
FROM orders o 
INNER JOIN order_lines ol 
ON o.order_id = ol.order_id 
WHERE o.deadline_time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
group by o.order_id
```

This will return

```
Order_id   manufacturer
1          sony, panasonic
2          sony
```

---

```
SELECT o.order_id,
CASE WHEN count(distinct(ol.product_manufacturer )) >1  
                  THEN '999' ELSE product_manufacturer END as manufacturerid  
FROM orders o 
INNER JOIN order_lines ol 
ON o.order_id = ol.order_id 
WHERE o.deadline_time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
group by o.order_id
```

This will return

```
Order_id   manufacturerid
    1          999
    2          sony
```

Comment: u meant u do not want the order_id?

Comment: I do, but the manufacturer should only be one number, if there is more than one return 999 else return manufacturer id. Also it should be sorted by the manufacturer, not the order id. But that's just the order by that should be changed, I can manage that :)

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check it out.

Comment: U are my hero, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you cannot get that form of output from a single SQL command.
I suggest you to get `SELECT DISTINCT product_manufacturer FROM order_lines` and then search from all orders where deadline hasn't passed for each product_manufacturer.
For ex:

```
 SELECT o.order_id  FROM orders o, order_lines ol  
 WHERE o.deadline_time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() 
 AND ol.product_manufacturer='$pro_man'
```

Answer (score 0):

@UlrikMcArdle

why isn't the first query with `ORDER BY` what you are looking for?

```
SELECT o.order_id, ol.product_manufacturer 
FROM orders o 
INNER JOIN order_lines ol ON o.order_id = ol.order_id 
WHERE o.deadline_time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
ORDER ol.product_manufacturer, o.order_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ol.product_manufacturer 
FROM orders o 
INNER JOIN order_lines ol 
ON o.order_id = ol.order_id 
WHERE o.deadline_time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
GROUP BY ol.product_manufacturer
```

you can use some sort of UDF to concat all the order_id for the manufacture.

[Click here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) for similar UDF